# python - request.get("https://www.example.com") doesn't work when trying to run Django app with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, python-requests, python-2.x

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
```

This fails with error:

```
Exception Value: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

Tried all the steps mentioned [here](http://%20https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) without any success.

Is there any other way to start django server in production? Or any other way to run https requests on Python 2.x?

I have tried `httplib2` and `urllib`.

Tried installing `httplib` but couldn't install.

StackTrace:

```
None
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537433 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000] Internal Server Error: /myproject/createUser/
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537447 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537450 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537453 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     response = get_response(request)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537455 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537458 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537461 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537464 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537467 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537470 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537472 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537475 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537477 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537480 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537483 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537485 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537488 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537491 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537493 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 88, in get
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537496 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     aud,email = getEmailandAud(self,request)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537498 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]   File "/home/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 31, in getEmailandAud
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537501 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000]     response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" + access_token)
[Wed Jul 11 17:39:24.537505 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22236:tid 139944512608000] TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Could you post the whole traceback?

Comment: Print `access_token` one line above request and see what's getting printed. I feel that is causing the error.

Comment: @sP_ Thank you for that. Yes the problem was access_token. WSGI was blocking my authorization header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have in the question, is not what is in your application code. The error logs shows it has:

```
response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" + access_token)
```

The `access_token` at that point is `None` and why you get the error. As in:

```
>>> access_token = None
>>> "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" + access_token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

If you changed the code to remove that, you have not restarted the server to have the new code picked up.

To learn about restarting on code changes see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html

Comment: No, that is not the issue. Access token is getting generated. I have just mentioned in my question as "example.com". Access token generation is not the problem

Comment: All I can say is that the error disagrees. There must be a situation where access token is ``None`` when the code is called at some point. There isn't any other source for where the error could come from.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem was with access_token. Sorry for the silly mistake. Thank you for your time